# Change client IP to proxy IP for API requests

Tags: apache, reverse-proxy, nginx-reverse-proxy, clientip

Original client IP does not change when I use a reverse-proxy to use some API from an internal corporate server.

So far I've done what most people suggested on Internet.
Just putting in proxyPass stuff in Apache config files.
Basically the setup is like this.

Client browser -> Reverse Proxy server -> Internal server

Internal API that I'm trying to use is only open to reverse proxy because of obvious security considerations.
If I can just pass the Reverse Proxy server's IP to the internal server, it would just work.

```
<Location />
  ProxyPass ${internalServer}
  ProxyPassReverse ${internalServer}
</Location>
```

I've also tried
RemoteIPHeader ${myProxyIP}

It should connect and let me use API from internal server.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
<Location />
  ProxyAddHeaders Off
  ProxyPass ${internalServer} 
  ProxyPassReverse ${internalServer}
</Location>
```

Comment: Thanks, but it doesn't work..  Trying some other combinations of flags